# Is "kämpfen mit" equal to "kämpfen gegen"?

Tags: meaning, usage, meaning-in-context

> Ich kämpfe mit den Freunden.

Does this mean that I fight against my friends or not? Or it's context dependant?

Can I say the following?

> Ich kämpfe mit den Freunden gegen die Feinde.

Does it mean that I and friends fight against the enemy?

Comment: *Kämpfen mit* is context dependent, and your understanding is correct.

Comment: Related question (regarding *kämpfen um* vs *kämpfen für*): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9442/difference-between-k%c3%a4mpfen-um-and-k%c3%a4mpfen-f%c3%bcr/9443#9443

Comment: This has nothing to do with german, right? The problem exists in other languages, too.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Yes. The same is in my native language. But I need to make sure that it isn't [False friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the context

*Mit* in the sense of *gegen*:

> Ich kämpfe mit meinen Freunden um den ersten Preis beim Eierlauf.
>
> Beim Wagenrennen im alten Byzanz kämpften die Blauen mit den Grünen. Mal gewannen die Blauen, mal die Grünen.
>
> Paul kämpfte mit sich selbst. Sollte er der Versuchung nachgeben und mit Erna ins Kino gehen? Was würde Gudrun dazu sagen, wenn sie es erführe?

*Mit* in the sense of *together with*:

> Die Engländer kämpften mit den Franzosen gegen die Deutschen.
>
> Paul kämpft mit Erna für den Erhalt des Stadtparks.

Accordingly, **theoretically** you could say something like

> Paul kämpft mit Erna mit der Business-Fraktion des Stadtrats für den Erhalt des Parks

where you mean that Paul together with Erna fights against the business lobby in the city council for preserving the park. But of course you would avoid such a sentence as it is rather confusing. Whereever there could be any doubt, you will prefer *gegen* when this is the intended meaning.

Comment: I would say, that in the first sentence "Ich kämpfe mit meinen Freunden um den ersten Preis beim Eierlauf." it can mean both "fight against my friends" and "fight together with my friends [against another team]", depending on the context. Maybe the ambiguous meaning can come from the fact, that "Eierlauf" can be played both as a single player game and a team game.

Comment: @tallistroan  Yes, indeed, fully depending on the context. I just thought that in a typical (simple-most) situation of *Eierlauf* individuals are competing with each other, not teams. When you and your friends are a team competing with other teams, then... uff... yes, you know what I mean.